# traceback behaviour for __init__ errors when using __call__ in metaclasses?

Tags: python, metaclass, traceback

Using the following code:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcl, name, bases, nmspc):
        return super(Meta, mcl).__new__(mcl, name, bases, nmspc)

class TestClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

t = TestClass(2) # deliberate error
```

produces the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 12, in <module>
    t = TestClass(2)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

However using `__call__` instead of `__new__` in the following code:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance =  super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something
        return instance

class TestClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

t = TestClass(2) # deliberate error
```

gives me the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 14, in <module>
    t = TestClass(2)
  File "foo.py", line 4, in __call__
    instance =  super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

1. Does `type` also trigger the `__init__` of the class from its `__call__` or is the behaviour changed when I add the metaclass?
2. Both `__new__` and `__call__` are being run by the call to the class constructor. Why is `__call__` showing up in the error message but not `__new__`?
3. Is there a way of suppressing the lines of the traceback showing the `__call__` for the metaclass here? i.e. when the error is in the call to the constructor and not the `__call__` code?

Comment: Is this just a repost of your previous (now-deleted) question?

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce the issue in equivalent code for Python 3.4. I always see `Meta.__call__` in the traceback whenever I get an exception in `TestClass.__init__`. So, the issue may be Python 2.x only.

Comment: @Blcknght: sorry, my fault. Juca pointed it out below. The description for Q2 is not correct. In the real code I got no traceback entry for a __new__ but I did for a __call__. Somehow I confused the two when I was writing the example code and thought the behaviour was for __call__. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Instead of posting an "edit:" blurb at the end, why not actually change the earlier parts of the question? As it is, I have no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: @Blckknght: you mean all three or just the second one?

Comment: @Blckknght: I tried to rewrite it for clarity. That's the best I can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets see if I can answer your three questions:

> Does `type` also trigger the `__init__` of the class from its `__call__` or is the behaviour changed when I add the metaclass?

The default behavior of `type.__call__` is to create a new object with `cls.__new__` (which may be inherited from `object.__new__`, or call it with `super`). If the object returned from `cls.__new__` is an instance of `cls`, `type.__call__` will then run `cls.__init__` on it.

If you define your own `__call__` method in a custom metaclass, it can do almost anything. Usually though you'll call `type.__call__` at some point (via `super`) and so the same behavior will happen. This isn't required though. You can return anything from a metaclass's `__call__` method.

> Both `__new__` and `__call__` are being run by the call to the class constructor. Why is `__call__` showing up in the error message but not `__new__`?

You're misunderstanding what `Meta.__new__` is for. The `__new__` method in a metaclass is not called when you make an instance of the normal class. It is called when you make an instance of the metaclass, which is the class object itself.

Try running this code, to better understand what is going on:

```
print("Before Meta")

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        print("In Meta.__new__")
        return super(Meta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("In Meta.__call__")
        return super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

print("After Meta, before Cls")

class Cls(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self):
        print("In Cls.__init__")

print("After Cls, before obj")

obj = Cls()

print("Bottom of file")
```

The output you'll get is:

```
Before Meta
After Meta, before Cls
In Meta.__new__
After Cls, before obj
In Meta.__call__
In Cls.__init__
Bottom of file
```

Note that `Meta.__new__` is called where the regular class `Cls` is defined, not when the instance of `Cls` is created. The `Cls` class object is in fact an instance of `Meta`, so this makes some sense.

The difference in your exception tracebacks comes from this fact. When the exception occurs, the metaclass's `__new__` method has long since finished (since if it didn't, there wouldn't have been a regular class to call at all).

> Is there a way of suppressing the lines of the traceback showing the `__call__` for the metaclass here? i.e. when the error is in the call to the constructor and not the `__call__` code?

Yes and no. It's probably possible, but its almost certainly a bad idea. Python's stacktraces will, by default, show you the full call stack (excluding builtin stuff that's implemented in C, rather than Python). That's their purpose. The problem causing an exception in your code is not always going to be in the last call, even in less confusing areas than metaclasses.

Consider this trivial example:

```
def a(*args):
    b(args) # note, no * here, so a single tuple will be passed on

def b(*args):
    c(*args):

def c():
    print(x)

a()
```

In this code, there's an error in the `a` function, but an exception is only raised when `b` calls `c` with the wrong number of arguments.

I suppose if you needed to you could pretty things up a bit by editing the data in the stack trace object somewhere, but if you do that automatically it is likely to make things much more confusing if you ever encounter an actual error in the metaclass code.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, what the interpreter is complaining about is that you are not passing arg to `__init__`.

You should do:

```
t = TestClass('arg')
```

or:

```
class TestClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

t = TestClass()
```

Comment: Well, in 1, how is it the traceback being silent if it's there? You mean you can't see in what line of `__call__` `__init__` was called? In 2, if you introduce an error in the body of `__init__`, `__call__` is mentioned https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44ed8db67e80d9429163 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7283abfda0005f6ab9a2 and 3, in fact it has to do with `__call__` because the exception was raised in your `__call__` code.

Comment: 1. in a traceback for the class without the metaclass there is no extra line. It's just the testclass line, followed by the exception. I was asking if type.__call__ is called invisibly or if the behaviour is changed when a metaclass is added. Perhaps a stupid question but I wanted to be sure if what I understood was right. 2. yup, you're absolutely correct, the real code showed a difference between `__new__` and `__call__` and I didn't test the example code, sorry 3. see next comment

Comment: 3. the point is that the error is either in the `__init__` definition of the class or in the call to the constructor (as you pointed out yourself). The `__call__` code is irrelevant so it was confusing the users of the metaclass (i.e. the ones calling with badly formed constructors). I'd like to avoid that if possible.